# Calling .NET method from PowerShell with boolean parameter

Tags: xml, powershell, boolean, method-call

I'm trying to import XML node from one document to the other. I'm calling [ImportNode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.importnode(v=vs.110).aspx) method on XmlDocument with two parameters - node and boolean parameter.

```
...
$connectionString = $anotherWebConfig.SelectSingleNode("//add[@name='ConnectionString']")
$WebConfig.ImportNode($connectionString, $True)
$WebConfig.SelectSingleNode("//connectionStrings").AppendChild($connectionString)
```

but I'm getting an error

```
Exception calling "AppendChild" with "1" argument(s): "The node to be inserted is from a different document context."
```

I know that there must be something wrong with the import. I tried to change $True parameter to 1, 0, 10 and also remove it but it still doesn't help. It was surprising to me that even if I call this method with invalid arguments, it will pass without any exception.

What's the proper way to call .NET method from powershell with boolean parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have misdiagnosed the issue here - it's not the boolean argument that's the problem, but the fact that you try to Append the *original* node, rather than the imported node:

```
$WebConfig.ImportNode($connectionString, $True) # <-- great effort to import node
$WebConfig.SelectSingleNode("//connectionStrings").AppendChild($connectionString)
#                                                                      ^
#                                                                      |
#                                                       Yet still appending the original
```

Assign the imported node (returned from `ImportNode()`) to a variable, and reference *that* as an argument to `AppendChild()` instead:

```
$ImportedNode = $WebConfig.ImportNode($connectionString, $True)
$WebConfig.SelectSingleNode("//connectionStrings").AppendChild($ImportedNode)
```

Comment: Than you! I failed to notice that this method returns something.